# circular singly linked list problem with printing the liste

Tags: c, linked-list, circular-list

My problem is that the program when compiled doesn't show the last element on the list.
Apart from the funtions i will provide next, I have a function that initialises the liste and another one for adding elements to the list and they work just fine, now the reason I know this is because, say i entered 4 elements the "afficher_liste" function (that's supposed to print the liste) only prints 3. If i add a 5th element the "afficher_liste" funtion will print 4 elements if i add a 6th element it will print 5 elements. The new last element makes it to the list and is part of it, it just doesn't get printed. I hope I was capable of explaining the problem..

```
   typedef struct{
    char nom[20];
    float surface;
    int habitants;
    }ville;
    typedef struct{
     ville data;
    struct element* suivant;
    }element;

    typedef struct{
    ville* T;
    }liste;  




void afficher_ville(ville*v){
printf("****************info ville********************");
printf("le nom de la ville :%s \n", v->nom);
printf("le nombre des habitants de la ville :%d \n", v->habitants);
printf("la surface de la ville :%.2f \n", v->surface);


}
void afficher_liste(liste* l)
{
    if(l->T==NULL){exit(-1);}

    element *aide = l->T;
 int lg=0;
    do
    { lg++;
        afficher_ville(&aide->data);
        aide= aide->suivant;
    }   while(aide->suivant != l->T);

    printf("longeur* %d\n",lg);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the shown code. Though replace `exit(-1)` with `return` as an empty list has a right to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your exit condition is that the next node is null and following your logic, on the last node, your application will exit, instead of printing that node.

Breaking the recursion and then manually printing the last line before exiting the application will fix the issue.

I hope this helps!